# How do I determine a word boundary in Unicode stream in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

I'm reading a Unicode stream and would rather not have to pass the entire string through a regex.  Is there a simple (reliable) character I can use to break words across languages?

My byte array is likely going to be based in UTF-16 or UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java then you can use the [BreakIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html).